# merge columns on a key sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables that needs to be merged based on a key.

Table-1

[image]

Table-2

[image]

Output:

[image]

Query Used:

```
select  TB1.EMP_NUM , TB1.EMP_NAME , TB1.EMP_SALARY , TB2.EMP_AGE 
            from EMPLOYEE_MERGE_1 tb1 full outer join EMPLOYEE_MERGE_2 tb2 ON TB1.EMP_NUM = TB2.EMP_NUM
```

Expected Output:

For last record, Emp_num, emp_name, emp_salary should be populated from table-1, since I'm using a full outer join its making it nulls.. I can add the null checks to key columns(emp_num) and columns form table_1(emp_name & emp_salary) and populate accordingly but worried if it contain actual null values...

Answer (score 0):

What about this? This will give you TB2 values for EMP_NUM and EMP_NAME if there is no matching row in TB1.

```
select COALESCE(TB1.EMP_NUM, TB2.EMP_NUM) AS EMP_NUM, 
    COALESCE(TB1.EMP_NAME, TB2.EMP_NAME) AS EMP_NAME, 
    TB1.EMP_SALARY, TB2.EMP_AGE 
from EMPLOYEE_MERGE_1 tb1 full outer join EMPLOYEE_MERGE_2 tb2 ON TB1.EMP_NUM = TB2.EMP_NUM
```

Comment: If tb1.EMP_NUM and tb1.emp_name has actual null values, then I should not populate tb2.emp_num & tb2.emp_name

Comment: @user1050619 What do you plan on doing with the rows in TB2 that don't have a matching EMP_NUM in TB1? If this won't ever be the case then you should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Otherwise, you'd at least want to keep the `COALESCE` for EMP_NUM, then maybe use a `CASE` statement for EMP_NAME where you check for `TB1.EMP_NUM IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TB1.EMP_NUM , coalesce(TB1.EMP_NAME,TB2.EMP_NAME) , TB1.EMP_SALARY , TB2.EMP_AGE 
from EMPLOYEE_MERGE_1 tb1 full outer join EMPLOYEE_MERGE_2 tb2 
ON TB1.EMP_NUM = TB2.EMP_NUM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @list1 AS TABLE (Emp_Num INT, Emp_Name VARCHAR(100), Emp_Salary MONEY)
DECLARE @list2 AS TABLE (Emp_Num INT, Emp_Name VARCHAR(100), Emp_Age INT)

INSERT INTO @list1 
          SELECT 1, 'TOM', 5000
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'BRIAN', 6000
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'RAM', 8000
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'DINESH', 8000


INSERT INTO @list2 
          SELECT 1, 'TOM', 20
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'BRIAN', 40
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'RAM', 60
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'SARATH', 90

;WITH list AS (
SELECT Emp_Num, Emp_Name FROM @list1
UNION
SELECT Emp_Num, Emp_Name FROM @list2
)
SELECT L0.Emp_Num, L0.Emp_Name, EMP_SALARY = L1.Emp_Salary, EMP_AGE = L2.Emp_Age
FROM list AS L0
LEFT OUTER JOIN @list1 L1 ON L1.Emp_Num = L0.Emp_Num
LEFT OUTER JOIN @list2 L2 ON L2.Emp_Num = L0.Emp_Num



-- OUTPUT 
Emp_Num   Emp_Name    EMP_SALARY  EMP_AGE
1         TOM         5000.00     20
2         BRIAN       6000.00     40
3         RAM         8000.00     60
4         DINESH      8000.00     NULL
5         SARATH      NULL        90
```